# Animate a view (button) with the keyboard showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation, nslayoutconstraint

I have a button at the bottom of my main view and I want to animate it up with the keyboard when it is showing.

My button is set like this with a constraint in my storyboard :

[image]

I have linked the constraint in the code:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint;
```

Added a notification when keyboard is showing:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

And here is the `keyboardWillShow` implementation:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow: (NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = notification.userInfo;
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [dictionary[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
        self.myConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height + 18;
    }];
}
```

Although it works, the button doesn't animate but instead is immediately set at its new location on the view. I tried to add a completion block to see what happens, and actually the completion is immediately called instead of waiting a second as it should...

What is wrong? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing that requires animation is the layout triggered by the constraint change....

```
self.myConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height + 18;
[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
   [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Comment: Got it ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss `layoutIfNeed` for the `UIView` you want to update with new constraint value.

You should try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce the animation delay to **0.3**. The keyboard's speed animation is more greater than your button's speed animation.

Also you need to **setNeedsLayout** to your button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could get it done thanks to danh answer, and about the animation delay, I improved it by retrieving the keyboard hiding/showing duration as a NSNumber : `NSNumber *duration = dictionary[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]`, then used it like this : `animateWithDuration:[duration doubleValue]`.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for the same results in Swift 5.3:

```
@IBOutlet weak var loginButtonConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}


// MARK: - Functions

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else { return }
    
    self.loginButtonConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height + 20
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2,
                   animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                   })
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.loginButtonConstraint.constant = 20
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2,
                   animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                   })
}
```